# print jobs dissappear

Tags: printing, hp

I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 with an HP Laserjet P 1005 printer. Yesterday I upgrade hplib to 3.16.3+repac.

Now it takes a very long time for my printer to process the jobs. And reports that the print job is finished without printing anything at all.

What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was much easier to solve than I ever thought possible. A friend gave me the advice to delete the printer in System Settings > Printers. Then add the printer again. That worked like a charm.